# How to pass parameters to in the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method to update / insert a XML node?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

Afther reading this post [How to pass parameters to the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method). I was hoping that there would be a option to use SqlParameter for updating XML nodes in a sql db. A example of the code I am using now, but this is not save at all.

```
string name = "Really Big Train";
string traintype = "AT1";

string sql = "UPDATE Trains SET TrainsRef.modify('replace value of(//name/text())[1] with (\"" + name + "\")') Where TrainsRef.value('(//traintype)[1]', 'varchar(3)') = " + traintype;

int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

When I somehow try to use a SqlParameter they are not passed as I expected.

When using

```
string sql = "UPDATE Trains SET TrainsRef.modify('replace value of(//name/text())[1] with (\"@name\")') Where TrainsRef.value('(//traintype)[1]', 'varchar(3)') = @traintype" ;

int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                              new SqlParameter("name", "Realy Big Train"),
                              new SqlParameter("traintype", "AT1")
                              );
```

The XML in the DB is not Updated at all

When I am using

```
string sql = "UPDATE Trains SET TrainsRef.modify('replace value of(//name/text())[1] with (\"@name\")') Where TrainsRef.value('(//traintype)[1]', 'varchar(3)') = 'AT1'" ;

int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                              new SqlParameter("name", "Realy Big Train")
                              );
```

The XML node is updated littarly with @name and not with "Realy Big Train"

ps {@p1} method is also not working, is also littarly added to the node

Comment: Does your statement work when executed from Management Studio? Not much point trying to pass parameters to a query that can't run

Comment: Why didn't i think of that :(. Thanks for the tip. When i run the Query in MSSMS, I got the Following Error "Getting 'The argument 1 of the xml data type method “modify” must be a string literal' while inserting a attribute in xml" --> this lead me to this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628368/2910930) and I got my answer. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your statements use different names for the placeholders and the parameters. A parameter name contains the `@` prefix. In one case you added quotes around a parameter placeholder essentially converting it to a literal. 
You should try the following statement

```
string sql = "UPDATE Trains SET TrainsRef.modify('replace value of(//name/text())[1] " +
    " with (@name)') Where TrainsRef.value('(//traintype)[1]', 'varchar(3)') = @traintype" ;

int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                          new SqlParameter("name", "Realy Big Train"),
                          new SqlParameter("traintype", "AT1")
                          );
```

You should also first try to get the query to work in Management Studio before trying to execute it through EF. Does the following work?

```
declare @name varchar(50)='Really Big Train';
delcare @traintype varchar(3) = 'AT1';

UPDATE Trains 
SET TrainsRef.modify('replace value of(//name/text())[1] with (@name)') 
Where TrainsRef.value('(//traintype)[1]', 'varchar(3)') = @traintype"
```

If it doesn't it won't work through EF either

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Panagiotis for helping me finding my own answer :).

For updating XML with parameters you wil need sql:variable("@parameter")

Replacing value existing XMLnode

```
sql = @"UPDATE Trains SET TrainsRef.modify('replace value of(//name/text())[1] with sql:variable(""@name"")')";

int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                      new SqlParameter("name", "Realy Big Train"));
```

Replacing value new XMLnode

```
sql = @"UPDATE Trains SET TrainsRef.modify('insert <name>{sql:variable(""@mdo"")}</name> into (/Revalidant)[1]')')";

int result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                      new SqlParameter("name", "Realy Big Train"));
```